# Styling Angular Material Paginator

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-paginator

I have an Angular Material Paginator that looks like

[image]

I want to style it and it should look like

[image]

I am having a very difficult time to style it. I was just able to move the elements in the paginator around(start and end positions), apart from this I was not able to modify anything.

Please let me know how to do the required styling ?

Here is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjhkpo

Comment: please share your code in stackblitz fork and show us link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material

Comment: it is the only way we can help you (please put in blitz only relevant code)

Comment: Here you go [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjhkpo) I want to style the paginator in the table as the target paginator  shown in my question     @לבנימלכה

Comment: nice! add this link to question

Comment: I have added the link !

Answer (score 11):

Use this css(for more style open F12 and override material declaretion):

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjhkpo-fdkekb?file=app/table-pagination-example.css)

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator-page-size-select {
    width: 27px!important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::ng-deep .mat-select-value {
  color: #005999;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}
::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
    color: #005999;
}
::ng-deep .mat-option{
  padding: 0!important;

}
::ng-deep .mat-option-text {

    text-align: right;
}
```

For captions modifying you should provide MatPaginatorIntl. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5mgfxh)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and such a quick response! but if you see the target paginator- It has 1-15 of 40 items. So currently the code shows as 1-10 of 11. How to add this 'items'. Also the navigation arrows should get shifted to the right side.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to add 'items' after 1-10 of 11 ? It should look like 1-10 of 11 items

Comment: i think you can not control it

Comment: Yeah... I guess so!

Answer (score 3):

If you use separate style for components and you want style child component you need to use in your `css` style `::ng-deep` before you style child component selector, for example:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-value {
  border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `::ng-deep` try to add more restrictive selectors so that you reduce the risk of side-effects e.g.

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-select-panel[aria-label="Items per page:"] {
    .mat-option-text {
      font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
  }
}
```